# Syntax error sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a database with two tables in it. However, this syntax error keeps coming up whenever i try to run it. I've checked through many times but still can't figure what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COL_1 = "Name";
private static final String COL_2 = "Pass";
private static final String COL_3 = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_ID1 = "id";

private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "staff";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Staff Name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "Staff Email";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "Staff Password";
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id integer primary key not null , " +
        "name text not null , pass text not null, email text not null);";

private static final String TABLE_CREATE2 = "create table staff (id integer primary key not null , " +
        "name text not null , password text not null, email text not null);";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE2);
    this.db = db;

}

public void insertContact(Contact c)
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_ID , count);
    values.put(COL_1 , c.getName());
    values.put(COL_2 , c.getPass());
    values.put(COL_3, c.getEmail());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String searchPass(String name)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select Name, Pass from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            a = cursor.getString(0);


            if(a.equals(name))
            {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return b;

}

public void insertStaff(Staff s)
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

    String query1 = "select * from staff";
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1 , null);
    int count = cursor1.getCount();

    values1.put(COLUMN_ID1 , count);
    values1.put(COLUMN_NAME , s.getStaffname());
    values1.put(COLUMN_EMAIL , s.getStaffemail());
    values1.put(COLUMN_PASS , s.getStaffpass());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME2 , null , values1);
    db.close();

}

public String searchStaff(String name)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query1 = "select name, password from " + TABLE_NAME2;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            a=cursor1.getString(0);
            b=cursor1.getString(1);

            if (a.equals(name))
            {
                b = cursor1.getString(1);
                break;
            }

        }
        while(cursor1.moveToNext());
    }

    return b;
}




@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    this.onCreate(db);






}
}
```

Logcat

> 02-06 17:13:32.552    9101-9101/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "Password": syntax error
>   02-06 17:13:32.552    9101-9101/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting id=0 Staff Password= Staff Email= Staff Name=
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Password": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO staff(id,Staff Password,Staff Email,Staff Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
>               at com.example.username.mp.DatabaseHelper.insertStaff(DatabaseHelper.java:106)
>               at com.example.username.mp.Signup.onRegClick(Signup.java:47)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Signup.java

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper1 = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
}

public void onRegClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()== R.id.button20)
    {
        EditText name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        EditText email1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        EditText pass3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        EditText pass4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText15);

        String name1str = name1.getText().toString();
        String email1str = email1.getText().toString();
        String pass3str = pass3.getText().toString();
        String pass4str = pass4.getText().toString();

        if(!pass3str.equals(pass4str))
        {
            Toast pop = Toast.makeText(Signup.this , "Password don't match" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pop.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Staff s = new Staff();
            s.setStaffname(name1str);
            s.setStaffemail(email1str);
            s.setStaffpass(pass3str);

            helper1.insertStaff(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signup, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove spaces from `COLUMN_NAME`,`COLUMN_EMAIL` and `COLUMN_PASS` values.

Comment: hey thank you for the response. do you mean removing spaces meaning COLUMN_NAME="Staff Name"; ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Unfortunately the exact same error still pops up :(

Comment: Ok. Do you change the variables in the DatabaseHelper class  COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_EMAIL and COLUMN_PASS in order to remove spaces? (for example, like: COLUMN_NAME = "Staff_Name" , COLUMN_PASS="Staff_Password" etc.)

Comment: hey i changed it and the syntax error is gone. however this new error message pops up **table staff has no column named Staff_Name**. any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Ok, maybe because you have changed the structure of your db, and so you are trying to search in the old version. Try to change the DATABASE_VERSION variable (to 3) inside the DatabaseHelper class. In this way, Android will execute the code inside the onUpgrade method, and thus will DROP your tables and then recreate them.

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to accept the answer please